# Which to use: "AcceptGet, AcceptPost"(MvcContrib) vs. AcceptVerbs(ASP.NET Mvc)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC controller methods can be decorated to accept on specific HTTP Methods(Get, Post, Get.. etc). Between MvcContrib and ASP.NET MVC there are 3 classes: "AcceptGet, AcceptPost" and AcceptVerbs. All three: "AcceptGet, AcceptPost" and AcceptVerbs do the same thing. They specify what http method is allowed to access a action/method.

AcceptGet and AcceptPost are in the MvcContrib. While AcceptVerbs is native to the Mvc framework. Which is better to use?

**AcceptGet/AcceptPost (MvcContrib)**

```
/// <returns></returns>
[AcceptGet]
public ActionResult Profile(string id)
```

**AcceptVerbs(ASP.NET Mvc)**

```
/// <returns></returns>
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult EditRequest(string id)
```

Documentation for the MvcContrib project's AcceptPost can be found [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=AcceptPostAcceptGet&referringTitle=Home).

It appears AcceptGet and AcceptPost were created to fill a gap in one of the earlier versions of the ASP.NET Mvc framework. The AcceptGet and AcceptPost classes provided a  strongly typed HttpMethod attribute.

ASP.NET MVC released with AcceptVerbs which takes an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum HttpVerbs
{
    Delete = 8,
    Get = 1,
    Head = 0x10,
    Post = 2,
    Put = 4
}
```

My question is which one is a better implementation, AcceptGet/AcceptPost or AcceptVerbs(with HttpVerbs enum type)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a great deal of difference between the two implementations but given that

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult EditRequest(string id)
```

is part of the framework now, I always use this. Both are strongly typed so there's no real difference there, and the HttpVerbs enum includes Delete, Head and Put which aren't in the MVC contrib version.

Answer (score 2):

As of ASP.Net MVC 2 Preview 1 release the following attributes are in the core MVC framework - HttpPost, HttpGet, HttpDelete, HttpPut. Of course the AcceptVerbs attribute is still supported.

So if you are using MVC 2 then you can use these new attributes and not require the MVC Contrib versions of AcceptPost and AcceptGet.